# Find Lax pair for solid body equations

Tags: integrable-systems, lax-pair

Consider the system
$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{u_1}&=u_2u_3\\
\dot{u_2}&=u_3u_1\\
\dot{u_3}&=u_1u_2.
\end{align*}
$$

In the book "Integrable systems" by Hitchin et al., it is said, on p. 3, that

> > The point where most discussions of integrability begin is with the idea of a system of differential equations which can be put in Lax pair form. Let's begin with a finite-dimensional system
> > $$
> > \frac{dA}{dt}=[A,B]
> > $$
> > where
> > $$
> > A(z)=A_0+zA_1+\cdots +z^nA_n,\quad B(z)=B_0+zB_1+\cdots + z^m B_m
> > $$
> > are polynomials of $k\times k$ matrices.

Unfortunately, the book does not say what $[A,B]$ is supposed to mean. From asking the internet, I guess $[A,B]=AB-BA$.

Then, on p. 5, the book says:

> > Many finite-dimensional integrable systems fit into this scheme, and in particular the rigid body, where we can take
> > $$
> > A(z)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & (u_1+u_2)\\(u_2-u_1) & 0\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}-2u_3 & 0\\ 0 & 2u_3\end{pmatrix}+z^2\begin{pmatrix}0 & (u_1-u_2)\\-(u_1+u_2) & 0\end{pmatrix}.
> > $$

Here are some points which I do not understand.

- What is $z$ here (and does it depend on $t$)? It seems to be some parameter but I do not understand the role of it.
- Why is $A$ apparently $2\times 2$?
- What is $B(z)$ here in order to get the Lex pair for the system above?

---

Here are the pages of the book I am referring to:

[image]

[image]

[image]